# How to reuse UIView that drag and drop with stroyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

For example:

I wanna to create a project just like a Books list with many categories, It can be navigate like following diagram

```
Category -> Category -> Category -> Book 
                     -> Category -> Book 
         -> Category -> Book 
                     -> Book   
                     -> Book 
         -> Category -> Book
```

So I decide to use UITableView and Navigation controller to archive that

I have drag and drop a UITableView inside Navigation controller, If use click a Category Table Cell, will push a new UITableView into Navigation controller, the all pushed UITableView has same logic with each other, So I wanna to reuse pre-draged and pre-droped UITableView with storyboard, How to reuse?

Answer (score -1):

Let UITableView conform to UITableViewDrapDelegate and then implement some methods , it can require your requirement , but you can use UICollecitonView to do it, don't always use storyboard, you can use code to do it quickly.
And then you can use POP to module it